# two datatable download in single excel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I have two datatable with different fields and I want to download in both table as single excel.
I tried with same class name for both table.now downloading only one table.I want to display the first table above and second table below in a excel .
I have two tables with class name example.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dg0cbhrL/1/)https://jsfiddle.net/dg0cbhrL/1/

```
$('.example').dataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can, with that setup. DataTables is giving you two files, as you asked for each table to have its data exported. The third is your one. The only option would be to create your own file from the data within the table (you can get this with rows().data(), and not use the DataTables Buttons exporting.

Comment: You can also try out 
function exportAllDatatables() {

    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    var table2 = $('#myTable2').DataTable();

    //Trigger the button at index 2-1 (Wherever your export button in each table):
    table.button( '2-1' ).trigger();
    table2.button( '2-1' ).trigger();
}

Comment: by using trigger it getting separate files

Comment: Then the best way is to merge them then save it. which is possible by using rows().data(), API. Here you go :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241831/datatables-merge-jquery-javascript-functions-from-two-seperate-tables